# PDF with a back button on the iPhone/iPad in HTML5?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm trying to write an HTML5 application for iOS (not the routers) that opens PDFs. Right now I'm just using `<a href="some.pdf" type="application/pdf">`. This exits the application and opens the PDF in Safari.

How do I get the back button to take the user back to my application, or view the PDF without Safari chrome?

I'm using Sencha Touch and would deploy with PhoneGap.

Comment: No, target="_blank" doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an easy way to do this as your application is hosted in a singular UIWebView as well so displaying a PDF in it would result in the inability to display a back button or for the user to navigate back to your application.

The only was that I could envision to do this would be to write a PhoneGap plugin that would create another UIWebView set it to the PDF's content, and add it to the master UIViewController.  You would then set the view to be x pixels from the top which would allow you to display a back button in a toolbar fashion.  When they click back, the plugin unloads the PDF, destroys the view, and your application is still going. (You could also just create a View on top with a native back button that just hides the PDF's UIWebView when clicked).

Comment: The ChildBrowser PhoneGap plugin does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an `NSURLRequest` pointing to the PDF and feed it to your `UIWebView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfUrl]];
}
```

I don't know where you get your PDF from, but if you need to intercept the click on the link 
you can also do that by defining your `UIWebView`'s delegate

`-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.

Comment: That's cool, but can I do the equivalent in HTML? Or would I have to write a PhoneGap plugin?

Comment: what I thought is that you should be using a `UIWebView` to display your HTML5 content. If so, the approach I am suggesting should be easily feasible, although I am suspecting now that Sencha Touch might come into play here...